# multithread list shared performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list

I am developing an application that reads data from a named pipe on Windows 7 at around 800 Mbps. I have to develop it with several threads since the FIFO at the other side of the pipe overflows if I am not able to read at the given speed. The performance though is really pitifull and I cannot understand why. I already read several things I tried to split the memory to avoid bad memory sharing.

At the beginning I has thinking I could be a problem with contiguous memory possitions, but the memory sections are queued in a list the main thread is not using them any more after queue it. The amount of memory are huge so I don't thing they lay on same pages or so.

This is the threaded function:

```
void splitMessage(){
    char* bufferMSEO;
    char* bufferMDO;
    std::list<struct msgBufferStr*> localBufferList;

    while(1)
    {
        long bytesProcessed = 0;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(bufferMutex);
            while(bufferList.empty())
            {
            // Wait until the map has data      
                listReady.wait(lk);
            }   
            //Extract the data from the list and copy to the local list
            localBufferList.splice(localBufferList.end(),bufferList);

            //Unlock the mutex and notify
            // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
            // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
            lk.unlock();
            //listReady.notify_one();
        }

        for(auto nextBuffer = localBufferList.begin(); nextBuffer != localBufferList.end(); nextBuffer++)
        {
            //nextBuffer = it->second();
            bufferMDO = (*nextBuffer)->MDO;
            bufferMSEO = (*nextBuffer)->MSEO;
            bytesProcessed += (*nextBuffer)->size; 

             //Process the data Stream            
              for(int k=0; k<(*nextBuffer)->size; k++)
              { 

              }   

            //localBufferList.remove(*nextBuffer);
            free(bufferMDO);
            free(bufferMSEO);
            free(*nextBuffer);
        }
        localBufferList.clear();

    }

}
```

And here the thread that reads the data and queue them:

```
DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID lpvParam)
// This routine is a thread processing function to read from and reply to a client
// via the open pipe connection passed from the main loop. Note this allows
// the main loop to continue executing, potentially creating more threads of
// of this procedure to run concurrently, depending on the number of incoming
// client connections.
{ 
   HANDLE hHeap      = GetProcessHeap();
   TCHAR* pchRequest = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));

   DWORD cbBytesRead = 0, cbReplyBytes = 0, cbWritten = 0; 
   BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hPipe  = NULL;
   double totalRxData = 0;

   char* bufferPnt;

   char* bufferMDO;
   char* bufferMSEO;

   char* destPnt;



    // Do some extra error checking since the app will keep running even if this
   // thread fails.
   if (lpvParam == NULL)
   {
       printf( "\nERROR - Pipe Server Failure:\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread got an unexpected NULL value in lpvParam.\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread exitting.\n");
       if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
       return (DWORD)-1;
   }

   if (pchRequest == NULL)
   {
       printf( "\nERROR - Pipe Server Failure:\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread got an unexpected NULL heap allocation.\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread exitting.\n");
       return (DWORD)-1;
   }

   // Print verbose messages. In production code, this should be for debugging only.
   printf("InstanceThread created, receiving and processing messages.\n");

    // The thread's parameter is a handle to a pipe object instance.  
   hPipe = (HANDLE) lpvParam; 


    try
    {
        msgSplitter = std::thread(&splitMessage);
        //msgSplitter.detach();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("CreateThread failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
        return -1;
    }


   while (1) 
   { 
       struct msgBufferStr *newBuffer = (struct msgBufferStr* )malloc(sizeof(struct msgBufferStr));
   // Read client requests from the pipe. This simplistic code only allows messages
   // up to BUFSIZE characters in length.
      fSuccess = ReadFile( 
         hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
         pchRequest,    // buffer to receive data 
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR), // size of buffer 
         &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read 
         NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

      if (!fSuccess || cbBytesRead == 0)
      {   
          if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
          {
              _tprintf(TEXT("InstanceThread: client disconnected.\n"), GetLastError()); 
              break;
          }
          else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
          {
          }
          else
          {
              _tprintf(TEXT("InstanceThread ReadFile failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
          }          
      }

      //timeStart = omp_get_wtime();

      bufferPnt = (char*)pchRequest;
      totalRxData += ((double)cbBytesRead)/1000000;

      bufferMDO =  (char*) malloc(cbBytesRead);
      bufferMSEO =  (char*) malloc(cbBytesRead/3);
      destPnt =  bufferMDO;   

      //#pragma omp parallel for
      for(int i = 0; i < cbBytesRead/12; i++)
      {
          msgCounter++;
          if(*(bufferPnt + (i * 12)) == 0) continue;
          if(*(bufferPnt + (i * 12)) == 8)
          {
              errorCounter++;
              continue;
          }

          //Use 64 bits variables in order to make less operations
          unsigned long long *sourceAddrLong = (unsigned long long*) (bufferPnt + (i * 12));
          unsigned long long *destPntLong = (unsigned long long*) (destPnt + (i * 8));
          //Copy the data bytes from source to destination
          *destPntLong = *sourceAddrLong;

          //Copy and prepare the MSEO lines for the data processing
          bufferMSEO[i*4]=(bufferPnt[(i * 12) + 8] & 0x03);
          bufferMSEO[i*4 + 1]=(bufferPnt[(i * 12) + 8] & 0x0C) >> 2;
          bufferMSEO[i*4 + 2]=(bufferPnt[(i * 12) + 8] & 0x30) >> 4;
          bufferMSEO[i*4 + 3]=(bufferPnt[(i * 12) + 8] & 0xC0) >> 6;

      }

      newBuffer->size = cbBytesRead/3;
      newBuffer->MDO = bufferMDO;
      newBuffer->MSEO = bufferMSEO;

    {
        //lock the mutex
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(bufferMutex);
        //add data to the list
        bufferList.push_back(newBuffer);
    } // bufferMutex is automatically released when lk goes out of scope

        //Notify
        listReady.notify_one();

  }

    // Flush the pipe to allow the client to read the pipe's contents 
    // before disconnecting. Then disconnect the pipe, and close the 
    // handle to this pipe instance. 

   FlushFileBuffers(hPipe); 
   DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe); 
   CloseHandle(hPipe); 

   HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);

   //Show memory leak isues
  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

  //TODO: Join thread

   printf("InstanceThread exitting.\n");
   return 1;
}
```

The think that really blows my mind is that I a let it like this the splitMessage thread takes minutes to read the data even though the first thread finished reading the data long ago. I mean the read thread reads like 1,5Gb or information in seconds and waits for more data from the pipe. This data are processed by the split thread (the only one really "doing" something in almost one minute or more). The CPU is moreover only to less than 20% percent used. (It is a i7 labtop with 16 Gb RAM and 8 cores!)

On the other hand, if I just comment the for loop in the process thread:

```
for(int k=0; k<(*nextBuffer)->size; k++)
```

Then the data are read slowly and the FIFO on the other side of the pipe overflows. With 8 processors and at more than 2 GHz should be fast enought to go throw the buffers without many problems, isn't it? I think it has to be a memory access issue or that the scheduler is sending the thread somehow to sleep but I cannot figure out why!!. Other possibility is that the iteration throw the linked list with the iterator is not optimal.

Any help would be geat because I am trying to understand it since a couple of days, I made several changes in the code and tried to simplified at the maximum and I am getting crazy :).

best regards,
Manuel

Comment: not sure I'm getting it, but. If you have 2 "slow" operations that you want to multithread to gain speed, and they share a in/out buffer (with locking), threading won't be activated at all because of the buffer bottleneck. Does it apply to your case?

Comment: The splitMessage thead should treat the data afterwards. Now I simplify it to try to find out what is the problem. They don't really share the buffer but the linked list with buffers. I use the function push_back and splice to be as short as possible blocking the mutex. I also have the feeling that when the copy thread finished copying the data and the pipe is empty, the splitMessage thread is still really slow. It takes like 10x the times the copy thread needed to copy the data, just to go throw the data. I think this should't be normal, am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe Valgrind, or some other profiling tool, can help.

Comment: How do you create your named pipe?

Comment: If you want async I/O I expect you are using completion ports?